# Display Image that updates automatically on Raspberry Pi

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi2

I'm new to Raspberry Pi.  I have a small screen attached.  I'm looking for a command that I can use to display an image.  I got it working using fbi (https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruit-pitft-28-inch-resistive-touchscreen-display-raspberry-pi/displaying-images).  But here's the trick....I want to be able to have another application change the image that it is displaying.  So for example, if I login and run this command:

```
  sudo fbi -T 2 -d /dev/fb1 -noverbose -a theImage.jpg
```

Then, I have another application that is running as a service change theImage.jpg to be something else....how can I have fbi recognize that the image changed and refresh to the current image.  Ideally it would be close to real-time.  Any ideas?  Am I going to have to write an app to do this instead of using something like fbi?

Comment: good question I have same. Have you found answer ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use chromium to display a webpage, and have the image in HTML. Then you could use a javascript loop that would manipulate the image as you see fit using the set interval function. This would involved you installing apache2. You can even tell chromium to open in full-screen (kiosk mode) on boot, so your display is always running.

Here is my preferred method:
sudo leafpad /etc/xdg/lxsession/LXDE-pi/autostart

Add line: @chromium-browser --kiosk --incognito “localhost/index.html”

And your javascript program runs in index.html

I use this for more advanced display purposes but it should work for you.